# How to save uploaded files to C: in Django?

Tags: python, django

I have a PDF model in my Django project. I want to save these files to my C: directory instead of my project directory. ( Save to C:\otc )

I don't have to file it as in the model (customer_customer_name), I just want to save it in a file named otc in C:

And How can I add a timestamp to the uploaded PDF file's name?

**models.py**

```
def customer_directory_path(self, filename):
    return 'customer_{0}/{1}'.format(self.owner.customer_name, filename)


class Pdf(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pdf = models.FileField(upload_to=customer_directory_path)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='Select', choices=CHOICES)
    year = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='Select')
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now())
```

Comment: Maybe you can set `upload_to = r"C:/"`

Comment: @Sid I tried it but there is an error: The joined path ... s located outside of the base path component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `FileSystemStorage` as default file storage then `upload_to` is appended to `MEDIA_ROOT`. You need to change `MEDIA_ROOT` to `C:` if you want all upload be there or create new Storage for that field. More in [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.upload_to).

`created_date` field should probably looks like this:

`created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)`

otherwise all rows will have same value.

then you can try:

```py
def customer_directory_path(self, filename):
    filename = "{}_filename".format(self.created_date)
    return 'customer_{0}/{1}'.format(self.owner.customer_name, filename)
```

BTW: not sure where you got `owner` in that function.

EDIT:

you should be able to use also this approach if you don't want to create new Storage.

```
pdf = models.FileField(upload_to=customer_directory_path, storage=FileSystemStorage(location="C:"))
```